# No space left on device but enough space and enough inodes

Tags: linux

My system (openSUSE 42.1 64bit btrfs) says that there would be no space left on device, after doing a reboot. Some days ago I did system updates with yast. 3 of them (multimedia stuff) could not be installed so I chanceld and started teh update again, all did go well. On the next day I did reboot the system. Today I tried to do updates via ssh and discovered this error.

The system can do ssh to other systems but it is not pingable. Even doing a snapper rollback is impossible because there is no space left on device. I checked df -h and df -i but there are enough space and inodes left. What could be the problem? What could I check?

[screenshot of system error and df -h and df -i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpi8b.jpg) (Sorry for the poor quality)

Comment: Can you show copy-n-paste or screenshots of error message, and copy-n-paste of `df -h` and `df -i`? If the error doesn't make it obvious, what are you trying to do (especially, which file are you trying to create or extend) that leads to this error?

Comment: I did solve my problem. Used this link: https://www.opensuse-forum.de/thread/11439-gel%C3%B6st-no-space-left-on-device-obwohl-6-8-gb-platz-ist/?pageNo=3

Comment: For those who don't read German, it seems the problem was with BTRFS and snapshots . . . which is now edited in to the original post, which makes it more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Along with its many other crimes against good taste, btrfs has destroyed the utility of the `df` command, by having some contrained "metadata" space that doesn't show up in any of the usual reports, and which needs to be gently shaken now and then to let all the small bits fall to the bottom and leave more room at the top... or something equally inane.  To get a better indication of how your btrfs volume is faring, you need to use btrfs' own  `df` instead, which is, of course, underneath `btrfs filesystem`, so you need to run `btrfs f df` -- then, because enumerating filesystems is a Hard Problem, you need to manually specify the path to somewhere in the filesystem, so you end up with `btrfs f df /path/to/filesystem`.

Next, try working out what it's telling you.  Actually, we'll just skip that, because it requires a Ph.D and a fifth of OP rum.  Instead, just compare the `total` and `used` values for each line.  No panty-waist "Use%" column here -- or even aligned columes!  No indeed!  Read those lines like a computer would.

If regular `df` says you've got plenty of space, then the `Data` line will be showing as being OK; it's the dastardly `Metadata` that's probably killing you.

To correct that, you'll need to perform a rebalance.  Whilst I'm sure it's a terribly complicated and necessary operation, it does amuse me to think that a highly advanced 21st century filesystem has seen fit to recreate one of the worst annoyances of a filesystem that was obsolete when it was designed, back in the late 1970s, and worse, made it not just a performance problem to not periodically perform manual maintenance, but elevated it to an actual availability issue!

To do a pure metadata rebalance, you need to run this command then wait a little while:

```
btrfs balance start -v -dusage=0 /path/to/filesystem
```

After that completes, when you re-run `btrfs f df /path/to/filesystem`, your metadata should look a lot less consumed.

If that doesn't fix the problem, there's a lot more info (and a lot less snark) on various ways to clear btrfs filesystem full problems from [Marc Merlin](http://marc.merlins.org/perso/btrfs/post_2014-05-04_Fixing-Btrfs-Filesystem-Full-Problems.html), but I've never had to do anything other than a metadata rebalance to restore some degree of sanity to the situation.